# @Autowire on @Configurable working on local machine but not working on others

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, aspectj

I have quite strange problem. Namely I'm using aspectjweaver to inject spring beans into Vaadin windows. Everything is working fine when we are deploying app by Intellij to our local Tomcats on Win machines, but when Jenkins deploys app for our test server (unix) autowired beans suddenly becomes null. Does anyone have an idea what we may have done wrong? Below configuration:

Configuration Class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableVaadin
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class VaadinConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Class with error:

```java
@Configurable
public class MyVaadinWindow {

    @Autowired
    protected MyService myService;

    void myMethod() {
        myService.doSth(); \\ here I'm getting NPE
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I thought about changing from LTW to CTW but I'm getting some errors trying to combine it with Lombok which is also used in this project.

@Edit
I have managed to switch to Compile time weaving. I didn't expect it to work but somehow that fixed my problem. Anyway that is not the desired solution so I will wait for some other ides how to fix it while holding to LWT.

Comment: Check versions of JDK, spring, vaadin, aspectj etc. for local machine, Jenkins machine and test machine. Also check tomcat libs. Also check maven repositories cached on local machine etc. Check classpath differences. Check for tomcat locations differences. Turn on trace on spring level for autowire debug. Move @Autowired from field to class constructor and see error logs when it can't find prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go and post update later.

Comment: Most likely in your local machine the required java agent aspectjweaver is set up correctly (VM argument `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`), while on the test machine it is not.